# swap partition limits my drive

Tags: swap, partitioning

Why is the swap disk not just a file inside the main partition? Setting as a separate partition limits my ability to extend 1 partition for another OS.

Comment: A partition is easier to manage than a file, and is also a little bit faster: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2207/why-does-linux-use-a-swap-partition-rather-than-a-file

Comment: Can you just delete the partition (unmount, format) and then extend the drive and then partition it again to include a new /swap partition? I can't say that I've tried it but, you know... You can certainly go long enough without a /swap to do that. Again, never tried it but it's worth a look.

Answer (score 3):

I find that I never use my swap partition.  If you have sufficient RAM on your machine, you might be able to do without it.  Go to a command window and type in

```
free -m
```

You should see on the last line a reference to 'Swap'.  If the used on this is zero, and stays that way consistently, shrink your swap partition down with gparted or remove it entirely.

You could, potentially, use a swap file, but I am uncertain how reliable the technique is for doing this given Linux's emphasis on using a partition for this instead of a file.  If it turns out that you need a swap file, google 'swap file linux' and instructions on how to set it up should be readily available for you.

Comment: Not sure if it's worth mentioning, but you need a swap partition to hibernate. It probably doesn't mater though, since hibernation is disabled by default. Still, something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

You can make swap file and replace swap partiton with them.

Create swap file with this command

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=1048576
sudo mkswap /swapfile
```

This will create swap of 1 GB. If you want bigger swap change `count` value. Count is in `KB`

Turn on newly created `swap file`

```
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

If you want `mount` this file at the boot time, edit `/etc/fstab` and at the end add this line.

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

add

```
/swapfile       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

This is it.